# Auto Fill Month in blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have question how to improve my macro to go trough column A and when its find blanks cell then it will type there name of month?  I tried something like in below but its only work with `Range("A1").value` instead of `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

```
 Sub actual_month()
'fill month col

Dim arrMonths() As String
ReDim arrMonths(1 To 12)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
arrMonths(1) = "JAN"
arrMonths(2) = "FEB"
arrMonths(3) = "MAR"
arrMonths(4) = "APR"
arrMonths(5) = "MAY"
arrMonths(6) = "JUNE"
arrMonths(7) = "JULY"
arrMonths(8) = "AUG"
arrMonths(9) = "SEP"
arrMonths(10) = "OCT"
arrMonths(11) = "NOV"
arrMonths(12) = "DEC"

Workbooks("UAC_report_p.xlsb").Activate

Sheets("SLA Calculation").Select


For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
      'do some stuff
   Next



For i = 1 To 12



Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row = Month(Date)
  If Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Value = Month(Date) Then _
     Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Value = arrMonths(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row.Value)
   Next i




Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "when its find blanks cell then it will type there name of month?"......   That doesn't make sense to me.. Do you mean the current Month?

Comment: when it finds blank cells then enter WHICH month name? How would you know which month should be placed in each blank cell?

Comment: this month name, this will be running once per month but they want it automatize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the current month, you can do it like this

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim endrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Col As Long
    Dim arrMonths(1 To 12)

    arrMonths(1) = "JAN"
    arrMonths(2) = "FEB"
    arrMonths(3) = "MAR"
    arrMonths(4) = "APR"
    arrMonths(5) = "MAY"
    arrMonths(6) = "JUNE"
    arrMonths(7) = "JULY"
    arrMonths(8) = "AUG"
    arrMonths(9) = "SEP"
    arrMonths(10) = "OCT"
    arrMonths(11) = "NOV"
    arrMonths(12) = "DEC"

    Set ws = Sheet4

    'set column to "A"
    Col = 1


    endrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If ws.Cells(endrow, Col).Value = "" Then _
    ws.Cells(endrow, Col).Value = arrMonths(Month(Now))
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

A better way would be not to use the Arrays at all and use the `LanguageID` to get the Equivalent of the Month Name in a particular Language. For a complete list of LanguageID's, please refer to [THIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324097) The `LanguageID` for `English_United_States` is `409`

Try this code

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long, Col As Long
    Dim sMonth As String

    Set ws = Sheet4

    '~~> Not sure if Czech has same names as `Text` / `Today`. 
    '~~> If not then replace `Text` and `Today` with their respective equivalents.
    sMonth = Application.Evaluate("=TEXT(TODAY(),""[$-409]MMM"")")

    With ws
        '~~> Set column to "A"
        Col = 1

        Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If .Cells(Lrow, Col).Value = "" Then _
        .Cells(Lrow, Col).Value = sMonth
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: but problem is I am from Czech Republic and I want name of month in English like for November Nov

Comment: When its like this For i = 1 To 12 For i = 1 To 12 Range("A20") = Month(Date) If Range("A20").Value = Month(Date) Then _ Range("A20").Value = arrMonths(Range("A20").Value) Next i it work but only for A20

Comment: I added your month array back in then... I think you can change regional settings within Excel, but definitely wouldn't advise this..

Comment: I realy thank you for your help but it still not what I want to do. I want fill the NOV in column A under last fill cell

Comment: Just 1 cell under the bottom cell?

Comment: Yes just 1 cell under the bottom cell.

Comment: Third time lucky...  :) The update just does column A at the moment, but it could easily be extended to do more columns by adding a loop

Comment: I am curious can I add control to not add to next blank cell current moth? and Than msgbox appear and i will say sorry bro next month?

Comment: In the code, yes you could. Just use an `If ... Then ... Else ...` statement

Comment: + 1 :) May I suggest a better alternative by editing your post?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes.. Please feel free :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Nice tip. Thanks.. To avoid evaluate, you could use `Application.Text(Now, "[$-409]MMM")`

Comment: Yup I know :). I love testing my formulas first in the Excel sheet and then simply copying it across in `Application.Evaluate` :) That ways I don't have to use different syntax for different functions.